# How can I find the expected value of the max of two independent random variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I want to find the expected value of $\max(X,Y)$, where $X,Y$ are independent geometric random variables with parameters 0.3 and 0.6, respectively. My approach is to do something like

```
Expectation[Max[x,y], {x \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[0.3], y \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[0.6]}]
```

The only problem is I don't know how to tell Mathematica that $X,Y$ are independent. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way that you entered the distributions tells Mathematica that the variables are independent. To help the evaluation, use exact values for the parameters.

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Expectation[
 Max[x, y], {x \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[3/10], 
  y \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[3/5]}]

(* 47/18 *)

dist = TransformedDistribution[
   Max[x, y], {x \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[3/10], 
    y \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[3/5]}];

Mean[dist]

(* 47/18 *)
```

**EDIT:** With inexact parameters use [`NExpectation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NExpectation.html)

```
NExpectation[
  Max[x, y], {x \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[0.3], 
   y \[Distributed] GeometricDistribution[0.6]}] // 
  RootApproximant

(* 47/18 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you explain how the way I entered the distributions tells mathematica that the variables are independent?

Comment: The syntax that you used is the fourth syntax given for [`Expectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html) in its documentation: "Expectation[expr, {x1 \[Distributed] dist1, x2 \[Distributed] dist2, \[Ellipsis]}]
gives the expectation of expr under the assumption that x1, x2, \[Ellipsis] are independent and follow the distributions dist1, dist2, \[Ellipsis]."

Answer (score 7):

An alternative approach if you are interested in order statistics (in addition to the  maximum) is to use the `OrderDistribution` function.

```
dist = OrderDistribution[{GeometricDistribution[3/10], GeometricDistribution[6/10]}, 2]

Mean[dist]
(* 47/18 *)

Variance[dist]
(* 785/108 *)
```

The `2` in the `OrderDistribution` function tells *Mathematica* that you want the 2nd order statistic (of the two order statistics given that you have two distributions) which is the maximum in this case.  Use `1` for the minimum.

For functions other than order statistics the answer by @BobHanlon is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness (and/or fun), here is another way to approach the problem.

The CDF for the maximum of two independent random variables is the product of their individual CDFs:
\begin{equation}
F_\max(x) = F_1(x)\,F_2(x) . 
\end{equation}
Therefore, let

```
cdf = Simplify[
  CDF[GeometricDistribution[p1], x] * CDF[GeometricDistribution[p2], x],
  x >= 0 && x \[Element] Integers
  ]

(* (1 - (1 - p1)^(1 + x)) (1 - (1 - p2)^(1 + x)) *)
```

The probability mass function is given by

```
pdf = cdf - (cdf /. x -> x-1);
```

Check to see that the sum of the probabilities equals one:

```
Sum[pdf, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]

(* 1 *)
```

The moments are given by

```
mom[n_] = Sum[pdf * x^n, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] // Simplify

(* p1 HurwitzLerchPhi[1 - p1, -n, 0] + p2 HurwitzLerchPhi[1 - p2, -n, 0] 
+ (p1 (-1 + p2) - p2) HurwitzLerchPhi[(-1 + p1) (-1 + p2), -n, 0] *)
```

The mean and variance are given by

```
{mom[1], mom[2] - mom[1]^2} /. {p1 -> 3/10, p2 -> 6/10}

(* {47/18, 785/108} *)
```

Instead of computing the moments directly, we could define a probability distribution

```
maxdist[p1_, p2_] = ProbabilityDistribution[pdf, {x, 0, \[Infinity], 1}];
```

to get the mean and variance

```
Through[{Mean, Variance}[maxdist[3/10, 6/10]]]

(* {47/18, 785/108} *)
```

However, this approach seems to be slower than the direct calculation.